# MessagePack-RPC for C++のmakeでエラー

Tags: c++

CentOS6.6
gcc4.9.2

mpio及びmsgpack-cは正常にインストールできたのですが、[MessagePack-RPC for C++](https://github.com/msgpack-rpc/msgpack-rpc-cpp)のmakeでエラーが出ます。
エラーの内容は、

```
exception.cc: 関数 ‘void msgpack::rpc::throw_exception(msgpack::rpc::future_impl*)’ 内:
exception.cc:44:17: エラー: ‘RAW’ is not a member of ‘msgpack::v1::type’
  if(err.type == msgpack::type::RAW &&
exception.cc:45:12: エラー: ‘union msgpack::v1::object::union_type’ has no member named ‘raw’
    err.via.raw.ptr == TIMEOUT_ERROR_PTR) {
exception.cc:48:24: エラー: ‘RAW’ is not a member of ‘msgpack::v1::type’
  } else if(err.type == msgpack::type::RAW &&
exception.cc:49:12: エラー: ‘union msgpack::v1::object::union_type’ has no member named ‘raw’
    err.via.raw.ptr == CONNECT_ERROR_PTR) {
```

となっています。
インストールしたいのですが、自力では解決できそうにありません。
お知恵を拝借願えますか?

Comment: 回答欄に載せていたリンク [Better support for str/bin discrepancy · Issue #57 · msgpack/msgpack-c](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/issues/57#issuecomment-60763727) をこちらに移して、回答を削除しました(回答というより参考情報にしか過ぎないので)。

Comment: とはいえ、その回答で解決したとコメントがあったので復元しました。もし質問者さんが具体的な解決手順を覚えていらっしゃるのであれば、それを回答として投稿していただけるとよりよいかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

以下で同じ問題が報告されています。

[Better support for str/bin discrepancy · Issue #57 · msgpack/msgpack-c](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/issues/57#issuecomment-60763727)

それに対する回答が以下で、対処方法が記載されています。

[Better support for str/bin discrepancy · Issue #57 · msgpack/msgpack-c](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/issues/57#issuecomment-60873323)

ご参考までにどうぞ。

Comment: 無事インストールが終わり、簡単なプログラムを書いてみて実行を確認できました。ありがとうございました。